# Testing variability of parameters between groups

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, variance

I have 3 continuous variables I want to test across different levels of categorical variables. For instance, I have

1. species identity,
2. sex,
3. surface (dorsal or ventral), and
4. function (let's call them A, B, and C).

If I wanted to test whether the 3 dependent variables have more variation in males over females, on the dorsal over the ventral, and in function A over B, and C, is the best way to carry out these separately using $t$-tests with CVs or Levene's test/non-normal equivalents? Or will a GLM help integrate all these categorical variables ? i.e. something like

```
variable1 ~ sex * surface * function
```

The ultimate goal is to understand if function affects the variability of the parameters measured, along with differences between `sex` and `surface`.

Any help will be appreciated, preferably in `R` as that is what I am familiar with.